# About Keyboard layout remapping

Tags: keyboard

I'm a student in Germany, so I have to type a lot in German.
There's four additional letters in German, ü ä ö ß. Since I'm using a computer with US layout, I can't type them directly but by using alt key.
Ü by typing alt+u once then u, occasionally shift switch also, Ä by typing alt+u then shift+a. So it's a lot of keys, not quite efficient.
Since I only have to type these 4 letters, is there any way to make it a bit easier?
Like alt+u directly for ü, alt+a ä, alt+o for ö?

Looking forward for Help!
thx

Comment: You should also be able to type accented characters by holding down the key for the base letter and selecting them from the pop up that appears.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be typing in German for a while, it may be useful to switch to the German keyboard layout as needed. `Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources` You can use a keyboard shortcut or the menu bar icon to quickly swap between the layouts when working on assignments (but with much faster access to the accented letters you want.

[image: Input sources]

Otherwise you are looking at manually editing your U.S. layout to change the individual function of the keys, which is do-able but likely less desirable.

Comment: Most users will find difficult to switch from qwerty to qwertz.

Comment: If they're planning to spend significant time in Germany and will be using German keyboards, I'd consider it time well invested

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved by using Ukelele!http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele
Works super fine.

Comment: So I have assigned alt+a to ä, shift+alt+a to Ä etc. It's now much faster to type german. Otherwise I also assigned alt+e to euro sign €. Pretty good solution I think for people who wants to type german with a U.S. keyboard layout.